# How to use unobtrusive validation to make an input field required field if another input field is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a simple form with three different text boxes to enter the search criteria before a resultset can be returned. Among the three fields I want to make two fields conditionally required if the other one is empty.

In the attached screenshot the search form cannot be submitted without entering either the "Title" or "Performers" fields. It is fine if both fields have values. I wanted to achieve this by making "Title" as a required field when "Performers" is empty. But my code below doesn't work. I have the necessary validation at the server side. I am looking for a client side solution.

[image]

HTML Source code:

```
<form id="searchWorkForm">
        <div class="contourField textfield">
            <label for="searchWorkTitle" class="fieldLabel">Title</label>
            <div class="search-input">
                <a id="searchWork" href="#" style="z-index: 2000; margin-top: 0;"><img src="/images/profile-search.png" alt="" style="z-index: 1000;" id="profileSearch" /></a>
                <input type="text" name="searchWorkTitle" id="searchWorkTitle" class="text caps" value="" placeholder="Title" data-val="true" data-val-requiredif="title is mandatory" data-val-requiredif-otherpropertyname="searchWorkPerformer">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="searchWorkTitle" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contourField textfield">
            <label for="searchWorkWriter" class="fieldLabel">Writers</label>
            <div class="wideInput">
                <input type="text" name="searchWorkWriter" id="searchWorkWriter" class="text caps" value="" placeholder="Writer Name">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="searchWorkWriter" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contourField textfield">
            <label for="searchWorkPerformer" class="fieldLabel">Performers</label>
            <div class="wideInput">
                <input type="text" name="searchWorkPerformer" id="searchWorkPerformer" class="text caps" value="" placeholder="Performer Name" data-val="true">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="searchWorkPerformer" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Client side validation code:

```
$(function() {
    if ($.validator && $.validator.unobtrusive) {

        $.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
            return !(value.length === 0 && $(params).val().length === 0);
        });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredif", ["otherpropertyname"], function (options) {
            options.rules["requiredif"] = "#" + options.params.otherpropertyname;
            options.messages["requiredif"] = options.message;
        });
    }

    $("#searchWork").click(function() {

        if ($("#searchWorkForm").valid()) {
            // Make an Ajax Call and get the search result
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your `$.validator` method should not be inside `$(function()`. What problems are you having?

Comment: $.validator is inside the $(function(). The form doesn't validate. The ajax call is going through even though both the Title and Performer fields are empty.

Comment: It should NOT be. But its not clear what your logic is (and you have not should the code for the `ValidationAttribute`) - your `addMethod` is saying the form is valid if both are empty, and invalid if one or both have a value

Comment: I have changed the addMethod code to negate the condition. I have inherited this code where in many cases validation attributes are being written in the HTML directly rather than MVC create it.

Comment: If I add a data-val-required="mandatory" attribute on the searchWorkTitle field the code above works. But it will make title as required field all the time. I want to make is required only if performers field is empty.

Comment: You need to show the code for your `RequiredIfAttribute` so we can compare the logic there with the logic in your script. But based on your description, your `addMethod` needs to first check `Performers` - if it has a value, then return `true`. If not, then you need to check if `Title` has a value - if so return `true`, otherwise return `false`

Comment: I have no "RequiredIfAttribute" on the server side. After the form is validated an Ajax (HttpGet) call is made to a Json response. I am looking for a client side solution. I couldn't even trigger the validation with always returning false "return False" and with: return $("#searchWorkPerformer").val().length > 0;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128016/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tejsoft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to move the `$.validator.addMethod()` and `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()` functions outside the `$(function() { .. }`

But based on the description of what your wanting to validate, then the code in your `$.validator.addMethod()` method should first check if the 'other property' (`searchWorkPerformer`) has a value, and if so return `true`. If it does not, then check if `searchWorkTitle` has a value. If it has, then return `true`, otherwise its invalid, so return `false`.

```
// scripts for jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive
<script>
    $.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
        if ($(params).val().length === 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (value.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredif", ["otherpropertyname"], function (options) {
        options.rules["requiredif"] = "#" + options.params.otherpropertyname;
        options.messages["requiredif"] = options.message;
    });

    $(function() {
        $("#searchWork").click(function() {
            if ($("#searchWorkForm").valid()) {
                // Make an Ajax Call and get the search result
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Side note: `requiredif` does not really describe your validation - perhaps `requiredifempty` would be more appropriate since you only require a value if the other property is empty.